# Answer converted to comment, but answer not deleted

Tags: support, answers, convert-to-comment

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17906342/1699210) seems to be converted to a comment, since the user does not have enough reputation to comment on his own.

The question would be is why wasn't the answer removed?

Comment: Those are two different users. Flagging to have them merged though.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: Wow - I did not notice that. Nice catch.

Comment: well spotted bummi and shadow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The user simply posted his reply as answer **and** as comment.

You can see that there is a time difference (6 minutes, comment posted **first**) on both posts which indicates that it was not automcatically converted but manually posted.

And as @ShaWizDowArd noticed: These are even 2 different user accounts.

Comment: Thanks, didn't even notice @ShaWizDowArd discovery.